# How to put text in between a paragraph <p></p> tag on python/selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm testing some automation on a website and I encountered a `<p>` tag inside an `iframe`. I need to populate some text specifically between the `<p></p>` tags.

I've already tried using `.text() = 'some text'` but it does not work
I've also tried doing `.text('some text')` with no success

I was just recently initiated into python and selenium so this is really hard to figure out for some reason

Python Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser.get('www.somewebsite.com')
iframe = browser.find_element_by_id('IFR1')
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("p").text() = 'this is a txt test'
print('success')
```

I expect the `<p>` tag to have 'this is a txt text' but nothing happens

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? Selenium is primarily a tool for performing automated tests on web pages; it doesn't make a lot of sense to use it to alter the contents of a page.

Comment: I'm actually trying to fill out a form used by the company I work for from an excel file. I'm able to populate all other webelements except for the text box inside the `iframe` which has the `<p></p>` tags change when a user inputs any text in the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I was able to use `ActionChains(browser).send_keys('this is a test').perform()` in order to achieve writing some text inside the tags

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("p").innerHTML = 'this is a txt test'
```

OR

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("p").innerText = 'this is a txt test'
```

OR

```
aEle = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("p")
aEle.setAttribute("innerHTML","this is a txt test")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I tried all three of the options and even though the code ran all the lines it did not change the text between the `<p></p>` tags. It shows no error at all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("p").send_keys('this is a txt test')
print('success')
```